# hyperref with hyphens looks fine but nolinkurl ignores before hyphen

Tags: hyperref, footnotes, hyphenation

Not quite minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hyperfootnotes=false]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
Testing: \href{https://mathshistory.st-andrews.ac.uk/Biographies/Bezout/}{Étienne Bézout}\footnotemark{} did indeed prove a version of the Bezout identity for polynomials, the basics of u
\footnotetext[1]{\nolinkurl{mathshistory.st-andrews.ac.uk/Biographies/Bezout/}\label{fn-remark-bezout-d-b}}%
Ending
\end{document}
```

Everything looks fine, but the hyperlink itself in the footnote breaks off everything before the hyphen.  I found a lot of questions about *showing* the URL with/without hyphens, but didn't see one about this issue.  Any ideas?

Note that loading `\usepackage[hyphens]{url}` did not change behavior, which makes sense because it's the actual link that is the problem, not the typesetting.  Also, since I'm using a sort of required template, I'm not sure I can safely use the `xurl` package even if that were to be an easy fix, though I'd appreciate information about that.

Comment: `\nolinkurl` as the name implies doesn't produce a link. If you get anything clickable then it is your pdf viewer guessing.

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense!  I only ever use one pdf viewer, so I assumed there was some other functionality LaTeX was including along with that.  But I guess that viewer likes guessing.